# Center image inside parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is a common question but I'm struggling to center an image div inside another div. I'm using bootstrap. I use `margin: 0auto` `left:0` `right:0` and `position` but I'm unable to center the image inside `#abc` div.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s0ez9ag5/1/)

```
<div class="row abc col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class=" col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 coWrap">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 thumbnail">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://img42.com/uyrJW+">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 title coWrap">TITLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.coWrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.thumbnail{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.title{
    position: absolute;
}
.abc{
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #f60;
    position: relative;
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap has a class for that. Use the `center-block` class for the image. See the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: It's not clear what effect you are after. Do you have an image of what this is supposed to look like?

Comment: My answer works, but you are trying to center a image in a div withou space. Thank you for the downvotes, you are the most intelligent people in the world. If you try my fiddle you can see that display:block it works https://jsfiddle.net/s0ez9ag5/4/

Comment: The explanation: inline elements can't center with margin: 0 auto . YOU ARE SMART PEOPLE!

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks. I'm trying to center `title` and `thumbnail` inside `coWrap`.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude no it's not: http://scr.hu/678t/vl0rx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify top, bottom, left & right positions for absolute element in order to position it with `margin: auto`:

```
.coWrap {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

If you want it centered vertically remember to `margin:auto auto` or `margin:auto` in short and + provide a `height`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0ez9ag5/3/

Comment: @Becky You don't need to provide `height` in some cases and I would strive to achieve that; it depends on element and children `display` and contents; can't give example out of my head.

Comment: Hi @Szymon Toda you don't need to add .coWrap class to <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 title coWrap">TITLE</div> if you remove from there it will work too

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara it's irrelevant as in question it is as HTML source so I assume it's required. Anyway removing it from HTML as you suggested won't give asked effect ;)

Comment: Thanks. everything is fine except if it add multiple `coWrap` inside `abc` they over lap. Is there anyway I will be able to do as in my EDIT above?

Comment: @Becky Don't assing css to `.coWrap` but use other selection to target it or add special class to it. Your example had not multiple `.coWrap`s

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Yes, I had not mentioned about multiple divs inside `abc`. I've accepted your answer with a 10. thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Your .thumbnail is a inline element (  ) and doesn't works. Add this:

```
 .thumbnail {
    display:block;
 }
```

It works

Comment: Adding `display: block` to `.thumbnail` is not working in Chrome with code given in question.

Comment: Must to read, please, the image is in a div whos sizes 4 col , then there aren't space to center. Block element, with relative and margin 0 auto center EVER.